# recursive vs iterative factorial in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration, factorial

I made a shitty c++ programme to calculate the factorial of an entered value wherein I wrote two functions to do the actual calculations independently (one iterative, the other recursive). What doesn't make any sense to me is, why does the iterative factorial collapse at around n = 13 but the recursive goes all the way to the upper boundary of an unsigned long long int?

P.S. I would be grateful to receive any advice whatsoever regarding the quality of my code, and will happily amend it, thaanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned long long int rekursiv_fak (int); // function prototyping
unsigned long long int iterativ_fak (int);

int main () {
  unsigned int n; // factorial is defined only for positive integers !!
  cout << "Enter a positive integer value: ";
  cin >> n;
  cout << "The factorial of " << n << " is equal to: " << iterativ_fak(n) << " or alternatively " << rekursiv_fak(n) << endl;
  return 0;
}

unsigned long long int rekursiv_fak (int n) {
  if (n == 1)
    return 1;
  return n * rekursiv_fak(n - 1);
}
unsigned long long int iterativ_fak (int n) {
  for (int i{n - 1}; i > 0; --i) 
    n *= i;
  return n;
}
```

Comment: Good observation and pretty neat coding. Some additional points to check. Try rekursiv_fak with a very large number and see what happens. Also think about how you can make iterativ_fak work with large number. ;)

Comment: Notice that, in reality, `factorial(0) == 1`, whereas you return 0;

Comment: @sanojsubran thanks a bunch, I think that large input values would crash my poor laptop  cuz of the limiting behaviour of the recursive algorithm :(( as to how I could optimize it, I'm not so sure hmmm

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for the tip, I'll make an additional condition to check for null-inputs

Comment: @sanojsubran I think that the only way to make the `iterative_fak ()` work with a larger number is to make the parameter `n` an `unsigned long long int` but that still wouldn't work with very large numbers.. I heard there was another mathematical method using logarithms...

Comment: @AaronVracar You can use an array to store the result. Check this [implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/).

Comment: @sanojsubran yabadaba thakns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `iterativ_fak()` you multiply variable n which has type int. It is 32 bit type and can only store 12! at max. `rekursiv_fak()` on the other hand returns unsigned long long type variable and therefore has 64 bit to store result of `n * rekursiv_fak(n - 1)`.

Comment: but doesn't the `n * rekursive_fak (n - 1)` register as the input `n` of the next recursion? if so, shouldn't that be reported by the compiler as a narrowing conversion? I didn't get any such warning and the recursive algorithm returned the correct values up to and including `factorial (20)`
is the only way out of this to make both the function and the input parameter a `unsigned long long int`? sorta looks flimsy when I write it that way :/

Comment: There is no narrowing conversion, because you don't pass `n * rekursive_fak (n - 1)` as an argument to `rekursive_fak()` on next iteration. The argument it receives is n-1, which takes values 19,18,17,...,2 in your example of `factorial(20)`

Comment: @AaronVracar: in `n *= i;` you work only with `int`. with `n * rekursive_fak (n - 1)` you have `int * unsigned long long`, so `int` is promoted to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @AlexM4 oh yeea stoopid me, many thanks for the clarification !!

Comment: @Jarod42 I've modified the code to accommodate an unsigned long long int in the iterative function, thankss